# Bolt + Blake + Powell ever run together in a 4x100m relay?

Tags: trivia, olympics, track-and-field

I've gone through the best results [at alltime-athletics.com](http://www.alltime-athletics.com/m4x100ok.htm), but could not find it. The Rio 2016 Olympic Men's 4x100m Relay final will probably feature Usain Bolt, Yohan Blake and Asafa Powell running together for Jamaica. Have they ever run together before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in a global final before [Rio 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athletics_at_the_2016_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_4_%C3%97_100_metres_relay), which is to say, probably no.

Blake's breakthrough came in 2011, so he wasn't a factor in 2009. There was no global championship with a 4x100m in 2010. Powell was injured in 2011 and didn't run the relay at that year's World Championships. Since then, either Blake or Powell has not been on the team for each global championships:

- [2011 Daegu World Championships: no Powell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_World_Championships_in_Athletics)
- [2012 London Olympics: no Powell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athletics_at_the_2012_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_4_%C3%97_100_metres_relay)
- [2013 Moscow World Championships: no Powell, no Blake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_World_Championships_in_Athletics#Track)
- [2014 World Relays: no Bolt, no Powell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_IAAF_World_Relays#Men)
- [2015 World Relays: no Blake, no Powell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_IAAF_World_Relays#Men)
- [2015 Beijing World Championships: no Blake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_World_Championships_in_Athletics#Track)

So 2016 is the first time these two World Record holders and two World Champions (making in all, three) have been on the same 4x100m relay team. I suspect the last time we could describe a team that way (last two WR holders and last two World Champions) would have been a Carl Lewis/Leroy Burrell relay, and even then I'd have to check the history to see if it actually happened (or if Burrell ever won a WC).